# MD5 password hashing in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me, md5

I would like to hash my password in a mobile application using MD5. How do I do it? Please help.

Comment: md5 is not an encryption, it's a hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Fast MD5 Implementation in Java](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php#j2me), you may have access to [SATSA-CRYPTO](http://java.sun.com/j2me/docs/satsa-dg/crypto.html).

If you do not, they have an implementation of MD5 available, which should work on J2ME, is available [here](http://oplop.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Java/src/com/twmacinta/util/).

Answer (score 1):

["Compact MD5 class library for J2ME / JavaME app"](http://mobilepit.com/10/compact-md5-class-library-for-j2me-javame-app.html)

Comment: As an additional comment, this is from 2006, so there might be something better by now, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Just first Google link >_>  Anyway, MD5 hasn't changed, neither has J2ME, so this is OK

Comment: The MDTEST.zip download gives me an error 404 not found please help send me to email if u have it harrissamueldindi@yahoo.com please urgent would really appreciate

Comment: Sorry, try to use [Sebastian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524041/md5-password-hashing-in-java-me/5524060#5524060)